# how to make pinning of column off in ag-grid on first time load?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ag-grid

I have `ag-grid` configuration where pinning of column in on by default.
I want to off pinning of column.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowData: null,
        angularCompileRows: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableColResize: true,
        enableFilter: true,
        rowHeight: 35,
        rowSelection: 'single',
        onSelectionChanged: onSelectionChanged,
        isExternalFilterPresent: isExternalFilterPresent,
        doesExternalFilterPass: doesExternalFilterPass,
        overlayLoadingTemplate: '<span class="ag-overlay-loading-center">Please wait while your rows are loading</span>',
        overlayNoRowsTemplate: '<span style="    transform: translateY(-50%);opacity: 0.25;font-size: 3em;">No data available</span>'
    };
```

I did not find any proper way to make it off.
Is any one know how we can do this?

Comment: Were you able to make it work? A feedback would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish but the column API should solve your problem:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnPinned(key, pinned);
```

> Sets the column pinned / unpinned. Key can be the column id, field,
>   ColDef object or Column object.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/index.php